# How to initialize picture "blob" type in PHP constructor

Tags: php, blob

I have class and I want to initalize column that stores pictuer with type "blob" but I'm not sure how? take a look at the lat line of the code

```
  public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
    if ( isset( $data['date'] ) ) $this->date= (int) $data['date'];
    if ( isset( $data['topic'] ) ) $this->topic = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['topic'] );
    if ( isset( $data['author'] ) ) $this->author = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['author'] );
    if ( isset( $data['content'] ) ) $this->content = $data['content'];
    if ( isset( $data['picture'] ) ) $this->picture ="Here sholud be the Type" $data['picture'];
  }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP binary data is stored in strings, too.

So simply initialize it with `$this->picture = $data['picture'];`

Comment: In other words, PHP's strings are really just byte arrays.

Comment: @Iman25: Please do not forget to accept this answer if it helped you by clicking the grayed out checkmark icon on the left of this answer.